# Merge every x element in multiple lists to return new list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm writing a script that scrapes all of the data from my works ticketing site and the end goal is to have it send a text when a new ticket enters the bucket with all of the important info of the ticket.

Python 3.10

So far, it pulls from a scattered list and combines all of the elements into an appropriate group ie. ticket numbers,titles and priorities.

```
tn = rawTickets[0::14]
title = rawTickets[5::14]
priority = rawTickets[9::14]
```

With this I can say

```
num = x
wholeticket = tn[num], title[num], priority[num],
print(wholeticket)
```

and get x ticket in the list

```
# Results: "tn0, title0, priority0"
```

I want it to print all of the available tickets in the list based on a range

```
totaltickets = 0
for lines in rawTickets:
    if lines == '':
        totaltickets += 1
numrange = range(totaltickets)
```

so lets say there are only 3 tickets in the queue,
I want it to print

```
tn0, title0, priority0,
tn1, title1, priority1,
tn2, title2, priority2,
```

But I want to avoid doing this;

```
ticket1 = tn[0], title[0], priority[0],
ticket2 = tn[1], title[1], priority[1],
ticket3 = tn[2], title[2], priority[2],
```

[flowchart to help explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgh5Z.png)

Comment: Please provide sample value for `rawTickets` (in Python syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
tickets = list(zip(rawTickets[0::14], rawTickets[5::14], rawTickets[9::14]))
```

This will give you a list of 3-tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
l1 = [*range(0,5)]
l2 = [*range(5,10)]
l3 = [*range(10,15)]

all_lst = [(l1[i], l2[i], l3[i]) for i in range(len(l1))]
```

Or you could use zip as trincot offered.
Note that on large scales, zip is much faster.